# Camel Java DSL: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [META-INF/spring/*.xml]

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I have recently run into a situation with Camel after merging an unrelated change which has caused this stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [META-INF/spring/*.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:222)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:501)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:86)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:465)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:292)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    ... 21 more
```

The code merge did not mess with anything in the maven pom file and was relatively unrelated to Camel and Spring. I am using Java DSL to avoid having any xml files to configure Camel. This works if I remove the aforementioned code merge. I think this is an odd error related to my pom configuration to begin with... Does anyone have any experience with this error using Java DSL instead of the xml configuration? Is there a way to specifically mention that I am using DSL? If I am using DSL, it should not even look for an xml config file.

Here is the related section of my POM file for reference:

```
<org.apache.camel.version>2.20.0</org.apache.camel.version>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to remove the provided tags from any of the dependencies and it worked while launching the *spring application*, however, I am unable to get Camel to run independently with the mvn camel:run command.

```
<scope>import</scope>
```

This solved half of the problem which removed the roadblock for now.